# PHP Foreach with UL groups and LI

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, foreach, html-lists

I have the code below. $related is array result of db query and contains data.

Queried data consist of posts belonging to different groups (post_type). I want to group the queried objects within their post_type. The code below works BUT... what I want is create different ULs for each post_type. As it is below, there will be a UL element foreach post found in the query. So UL should stay out of foreach, but on the other hand how can i get post_type out of foreach? I am a bit lost here :(

```
$related = p2p_type( 'accommmodation-to-places' )->get_connected( get_queried_object_id() ); 
foreach($related->posts as $post) {
    echo '<ul class="related-'.$post->post_type.'">'; // this shouldn't be here
    if($post->post_type == 'hotels') {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->id, '48').$post->post_title.'</a></li>';    
    }
    echo '</ul>'; // this shouldn't be here
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, *group* the posts by their type:

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($related->posts as $post) {
    $groups[$post->post_type][] = $post;
}
```

Then loop through the groups and output the lists:

```
foreach ($groups as $type => $posts) {
    printf('<ul class="%s">', htmlspecialchars($type));
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        printf('<li>...</li>', ...);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```